# Issue with Angular calculated value not showing in JSON and not accessible for condition

Tags: json, angular, conditional-statements

I have a div that calculates annual income based on other inputs:

```
<div name="annual_income_calc" id="annual_income_calc" ngModel ngDefaultControl #annual_income_calc="ngModel" type="number" step="any" value="" class="large"  aria-invalid="false">${{monthly_pension.value*12 + monthly_investments.value*12 + monthly_annuities.value*12 +  monthly_SSI.value*12}}</div>
```

It works fine in the dom the amount calculates as I am putting in the amounts on other sections. However the final calculated amount is not showing in the JSON in console nor can I run a conditional on it. I am running hide buttons based on fields not being populated elsewhere like  .length === 0 and item ==''  for string and number but if it is not showing the final calculated amount in JSON that is a bigger issue.

I have tried (change)="($event)" and setting it to [(ngModel)]="annual_income_calc". Nothing seems to work.

Comment: You cannot put ngModel inside div, as far as I know.  Any entity that return a value can be coupled with ngModel, like <input/>.

Comment: Hmm okay so now that I no longer have ngModel on it how would i make is show as a JSON value? I took it off the div but now the key doesn't even show at all. Before the key with a blank value showed, now nothing at all.

Comment: So here is what I tried basically mirroring the output in a hidden input, but the value is still empty in the JSON.

<span name="place_holder_annual"  #income_output type="number" min="0" step="any" value="" class="large"  aria-invalid="false" [innerHTML]="monthly_pension.value*12 + monthly_investments.value*12 + monthly_annuities.value*12 +  monthly_SSI.value*12"></span>

<input style="display:none!important" name="annual_income_calc" ngDefaultControl ngModel #annual_income_calc type="number" value="{{income_output.innerHTML}}"/>

Comment: First, ngModel is written as [(ngModel)], which tells the Anuglar that it is two way binding. Also, span does not have type, min, step attributes. input does.

Comment: All of this I know. This was a fast change over without removing the items I had previously. Anyway I figured this all out with no help from any of this. I passed the variable into the model and it works fine no matter what the element.